# Salesforce 1 - Technical Feasibility

Tags: salesforce1-app, salesforce1-platform

Just wanted to know whether the following requirement is feasible via Salesforce1

We all know that Salesforce supports Email to Case.

In our org too, we have written apex code to suit our custom email templates.

One of the reasons why our users extensively use "Email to Case" is that they can avoid having to login to Salesforce to get a ticket created.They can simply create a case right from their outlook.

Most of our user base now have iphones and they are wondering whether they can have a mobile UI where in they type in the case fields (which they generally enter in outlook email template) and the case gets automatically created in SFDC.

I was wondering whether my solution to this problem is right.
Please feel to correct me or critique/advise if my approach is not right.

At its rudimentary form, the solution that I envisage will be

a) Create a simple VF page with four fields (Queue,Type,Area,Sub Area) similar to our existing email template

b) Expose this page as a public site (as they really don't want to login)

c) The site created from a) can accept input from anyone who can access it and create a case in SFDC

d) I assume that this simple VF page can be rendered "nicely" in iphones using Salesforce 1. Since it has a simple VF page I guess the performance should be fine.

Please provide your inputs :)
All are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

I think your requirements are somewhat mutually exclusive. If you have a page on a public site, then you can include that page in SF1 but SF1, unlike a public site, will always require the user be authenticated. And that violates your design goal of allowing unauthenticated access.

So you can put your case page on a public site, and you can also put it in SF1, but only the former will allow unauthenticated access.